# Is there any better way to avoid data skew by join in Redshift?

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

The query SQL as below cause one node of Redshift cluster disk full

```sql
insert
into
  report.agg_info
  ( pd ,idate ,idate_str ,app_class ,app_superset ,aid ,pf ,is ,camp ,ua_camp_id ,country ,is_predict ,cohort_size ,new_users ,retained ,acc_re ,day_iap_rev ,iap_rev ,day_rev ,rev ) 
select
    p.pd ,
    p.idate ,
    p.idate_str ,
    p.app_class ,
    p.app_superset ,
    p.aid ,
    p.pf ,
    p.is ,
    p.camp ,
    p.ua_camp_id ,
    p.country ,
    1 as is_predict ,
    p.cohort_size ,
    p.new_users ,
    p.retained ,
    ar.acc_re ,
    p.day_iap_rev ,
    ar.iap_rev ,
    p.day_rev ,
    ar.rev
from
    tmp_predict p
join
    tmp_accumulate ar
        on p.pd = ar.pd
        and p.idate = ar.idate
        and p.aid = ar.aid
        and p.pf = ar.pf
        and p.is = ar.is
        and p.camp = ar.camp
        and p.ua_camp_id = ar.ua_camp_id
        and p.country = ar.country
```

And query plan is

```
XN Hash Join DS_DIST_BOTH (cost=11863664.64..218084556052252.12 rows=23020733790769 width=218)
    -> XN Seq Scan on tmp_predict p (cost=0.00..3954554.88 rows=395455488 width=188)
    -> XN Hash (cost=3954554.88..3954554.88 rows=395455488 width=165)
      -> XN Seq Scan on tmp_accumulate ar (cost=0.00..3954554.88 rows=395455488 width=165)
```

[image]

From the above image we know `node-39` hold more data than other nodes. Because data is skewed by `join`.

To solve this issue, we try to use `update` instead of `join`

```sql
update
  report.agg_info
set
  acc_re = ar.acc_re,
  iap_rev = ar.iap_rev,
  rev = ar.rev
from
  tmp_accumulate ar
where
  report.agg_info.pd = ar.pd
  and report.agg_info.idate = ar.idate
  and report.agg_info.aid = ar.aid
  and report.agg_info.pf = ar.pf
  and report.agg_info.is = ar.is
  and report.agg_info.camp = ar.camp
  and report.agg_info.ua_camp_id = ar.ua_camp_id
  and report.agg_info.country = ar.country
```

Query plan

```
XN Hash Join DS_BCAST_INNER (cost=11863664.64..711819961371132.00 rows=91602 width=254)
    -> XN Seq Scan on agg_info (cost=0.00..2.70 rows=270 width=224)
    -> XN Hash (cost=3954554.88..3954554.88 rows=395455488 width=170)
      -> XN Seq Scan on tmp_accumulate ar (cost=0.00..3954554.88 rows=395455488 width=170)
```

[image]

The data is distributed evenly on all nodes according to the picture. However, there are more data in each nodes.

I want to know, is there any best practice of handling data skew by join in Redshift?

Comment: This [Choosing a Data Distribution Style](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Distributing_data.html) manual section seams to be related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-analyzing-the-query-plan.html

> Look for the following broadcast operators where there are high-cost operations:
>   • DS_BCAST_INNER: Indicates the table is broadcast to all the compute nodes, which is fine for a small table but not ideal for a larger table.
>   • DS_DIST_ALL_INNER: Indicates that all of the workload is on a single slice.
>   • DS_DIST_BOTH: Indicates heavy redistribution.

`DS_DIST_BOTH` in your first query is redistributing both tables on a specific column. You haven't included the column chosen in your `EXPLAIN` snippet but it's probably the first column in the join.

`DS_BCAST_INNER` is broadcasting a *complete* copy of `tmp_accumulate` to every node. Both of these operations are quite expensive and slow.

Your join is very wide and it seems like the first column is quite skewed. You could try 2 approaches to resolve the skew and prevent the broadcast:

1. Change the order of columns declared in the join to declare the *most* unique (or *least* skewed) column first. The first column will typically be used as the redistribution key. (NB: This would not work if the tables were already diststyle key.)
2. *Recommended*. Since the join is so complex and skewed you could *pre-calculate* a hash value across these columns and then join on that value.

```sql
--Example of Pre-Calculated Hash
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_predict 
    DISTKEY(dist_hash)
AS SELECT FUNC_SHA1(pd||idate::VARCHAR||aid::VARCHAR||pf::VARCHAR
                      ||is::VARCHAR||camp::VARCHAR||ua_camp_id::VARCHAR
                      ||country::VARCHAR) dist_hash
         ,pd ,idate ,aid ,pf ,is ,camp ,ua_camp_id, country
         ,…
     FROM …
;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_accumulate 
    DISTKEY(dist_hash)
AS SELECT FUNC_SHA1(pd||idate::VARCHAR||aid::VARCHAR||pf::VARCHAR
                      ||is::VARCHAR||camp::VARCHAR||ua_camp_id::VARCHAR
                      ||country::VARCHAR) dist_hash
         ,pd ,idate ,aid ,pf ,is ,camp ,ua_camp_id, country
         ,…
     FROM …
;
INSERT INTO report.agg_info
SELECT …
FROM    tmp_predict p
JOIN    tmp_accumulate ar
    ON  p.dist_hash = ar.dist_hash
;
```

Comment: I did not know `FUNC_SHA1` before, this solution save me a lot. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

The data is skewed because it seems the table you're joining with has all of its data on one node. This could either be because of the absence of a DISTKEY, or a DISTKEY which is highly skewed.

Therefore, you can either distribute the data of that table evenly across all the nodes, using DISTSTYLE EVEN, or select a different DISTKEY, which has more distribution in the data.

Comment: actually, both `tmp_accumulate` and `tmp_predict` are diststyle even. whereas, the data is skewed when `join`

Comment: Given the 70% of one column value is  `abc`, and this column is one of `join` condition. How to use `DISTKEY `?